# Funcionalidade de download com requisição via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo uma função de download com requisição via `ajax` em minha aplicação, porém não está funcionando.

Se eu acessar o endereço utilizando o método GET com parâmetro no endereço, o download funciona perfeitamente.
**download.php?opcao=download**

Mas se eu acessar o arquivo download.php via `ajax` com o script abaixo o download não é realizado.

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
<form method ="" id="upload_form" >            
    <input id="upload_button" type='button' onclick="download()" name="upload_button" class="btn btn-info" value="Download" />

    <br><br>
</form>
</div>
<br>

<script language="javascript">
    function download(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "download.php",
            data:  {
                'opcao': 'download'
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php

$reqmethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$opcao = verificarMetodo($reqmethod);

if($opcao == 'download'){

    $enderecoEntrega        = './';
    $nomeArquivo            = "teste.pdf";

    // Tempo máximo de execução
    // Parâmetro 0 para as conexões lentas
    set_time_limit(0);


    baixarArquivo($enderecoEntrega, $nomeArquivo);
}

function verificarMetodo($reqmethod){
    if($reqmethod == 'POST'){
        $opcao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "opcao");
    }else{
        $opcao = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "opcao");
    }
    return $opcao;    
}

function baixarArquivo($caminho, $nome){
    $validacao = false;
    $nomeArquivo = "{$nome}";
    $arquivo = "{$caminho}/{$nome}";

    if(!empty($nomeArquivo) && file_exists($arquivo)){
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='{$nomeArquivo}'");
        $bool = readfile($arquivo);
    }

    return $bool;
}
?>
```

Estou fazendo essa funcionalidade via `ajax`para não ter atualização na tela durando o download, e apesar de eu utilizar apenas um parâmetro na variável `data` do JavaScript, penso em utilizar os parâmetros com nome do arquivo e endereço para então ser realizado um `$enderecoEntrega = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "enderecoEntrega");` e `$nomeArquivo= filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nomeArquivo");` e ficar dinâmico o endereço e arquivo do meu download.

Se tiverem uma forma alternativa para solucionar meu problema, podem ficar a vontade para postar como resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O Ajax não funciona desta forma. As funções executadas no PHP só surtem efeito diretos para o usuário se a página PHP for aberta diretamente no navegador. Como o Ajax faz uma requisição para a página em *segundo plano*, por assim dizer, tudo que acontece lá no PHP fica lá. O que o Ajax faz é esperar (ou não) alguma resposta em forma de dados (uma string ou um JSON, por exemplo).

O que você teria que fazer é ativar o download do arquivo pelo próprio JavaScript assim que o Ajax receber como resposta de que a requisição foi bem sucedida. No caso do jQuery se dá através do callback `success:`

```
success: function(data){
   // faz alguma coisa
}
```

Onde o valor de `data` é algo retornado do PHP requisitado. Só que no seu caso o `data` seria vazio porque o PHP não está retornando nada (seja por um `echo` ou códigos HTML). Para exemplificar, vamos supor que o arquivo `download.php` tenha apenas o código abaixo:

```
<?
echo "olá";
?>
```

Neste caso, o valor de `data` seria `olá`. No seu caso, o que você poderia fazer é retornar um `echo` com o caminho do arquivo a ser baixado, por exemplo:

```
if(!empty($nomeArquivo) && file_exists($arquivo)){
   echo $arquivo;
}
```

Neste caso o valor de `data` seria o caminho do arquivo e você pode forçar o download com o código JavaScript abaixo, que cria um elemento de link `<a>` com o atributo `download` e fazer um click automático, forçando o download do arquivo, isso tudo dentro do `success:`:

```
function download(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "download.php",
      data:  {
         'opcao': 'download'
      },
      success: function(data){
         var a = document.createElement("a");
         a.download = data;
         a.href = data;
         a.click();
      }
   });
}
```

Porém vale ressaltar que o atributo `download` não tem suporte total nos navegadores da Microsoft (IE e Edge). No caso desses navegadores, em vez de abrir o diálogo para baixar o arquivo, será perguntado se você deseja abrir ou salvar o arquivo.

### Firefox

No Firefox (versão 64.0.2) o `click()` só funcionou se o elemento for adicionado ao `body`. Adicione o elemento e após o click, remova-o:

```
function download(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "download.php",
      data:  {
         'opcao': 'download'
      },
      success: function(data){

         var a = document.createElement("a");
         a.download = data;
         a.href = data;
         document.body.appendChild(a); // adiciona ao body
         a.click();
         a.outerHTML = ''; // remove o elemento

      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Tem alguma resposta com JS-Vanilla?

Comment: Vi algumas alternativas no SOen: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864791/4438007) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/4438007)

Comment: Cara, a única coisa que está em jQuery é o Ajax. Seria só trocar por XHR. Tá precisando usar?

Comment: Preciso, mas num projeto sem JQuery (ou com um acesso muito bizarro ao JQuery, mundo do GWT). Eu sei que o JQuery é só açúcar sintático ao XHR, mas não tenho experiência para dizer o que de cada coisa do JQuery se mapeia para o XHR vanilla.

Comment: Veja se era isso: https://jsfiddle.net/nf34ahdr/

Comment: Valeu! Era algo assim =3 só adaptar ao GWT e sofrer feliz